# How do I connect my IP Remote Camera to ZoneMinder?

Tags: ip-camera, zoneminder

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, ZoneMinder v1.29.1 with [this docker](https://github.com/QuantumObject/docker-zoneminder%20this%20docker) and [this camera](http://www.hikvision.com/en/Products_accessries_168_i5658.html)(hikvision ir panoramic fisheye). I can connect to the camera and I get the camera interface for settings etc. The problem is the live views need a windows dependent plugin, that's why I wanted to use ZoneMinder.

Now I configured everything according to [this guide](http://zoneminder.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userguide/gettingstarted.html). Basically I had to add a monitor, set the source to remote, set the protocol to rtsp, set the method to rtp/rtsp, set the host name to < user>:< pw>@< correct-ip>, set port to the rtsp port reported by the camera webinterface and set the host path to all possible things: I tried /Streaming/Channels/[1,2,3,4]/ and /live and /Streaming/Channels/[101,102,103]-[401,402,403,404]/ but I never had a live stream. I really don't know what I am doing wrong. Does anybody know the right host path or any other issues that could prevent me from receiving a live feed? According to [this site](https://wiki.zoneminder.com/Hikvision) the hikvision products should work with ZoneMinder. Maybe I am just missing something small and stupid, thank you.

EDIT:
I used ONVIF Device Manager to detect my rtsp stream: It is rtsp://< ip>:554/Streaming/Channels/101?transportmode=unicast&profile=Profile_101 and I use exactly those settings in ZoneMinder but it does still give me a 404 error on the video.

Answer (score 3):

Most Hikvision cameras don't work with the "Remote" option, but with the "Ffmpeg" option.
Source should begin with `rtsp://"username":"passwd"@"IP-ADDRESS cam":554`  and sometimes you have to append things like `/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0?tcp`
Protocol should be `RTP/Unicast`

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please read the guidelines and don't encourage off-topic questions by answering them.